# Variable in a postgres condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to be able to have binary variables in a condition statement:

```
select sum(t.hours), count(tk.id) from time t
inner join tickets tk on tk.id = t.ticket_id
where tk.active = :active_type
and t.billable = :billable;
```

`:active` type could be `'R'` or `'P'`
`:billable` could be `True` or `False`

I wrote it four times for each permutation but that is really just ugly.   Does Postgres allow something to make it more elegant?

Comment: What is ugly/inelegant about it? Not sure I understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results in a single query using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT active, billable, SUM(t.hours), COUNT(tk.id)
FROM time t
INNER JOIN tickets tk ON tk.id = t.ticket_id
WHERE tk.active IN ('P', 'R')
GROUP BY active, billable
ORDER BY active, billable;
```

If `tickets.active` can be only `'R'` or `'P'` you can skip the `WHERE` clause.